# Drawing produces texture error in Blender 2.93.6 and 3

Tags: draw-mode

[image]

I am quite new to Blender. I am also modding gun skins for Titanfall 2, so I don't know if it is the source blender addon, which might be the case.

There is a texture error whenever I try to draw on the model, no matter what color I use this remains. If I try the bucket the entire texture becomes just like the square in the image below.

I have tried both blender 2.93 and 3 to no avail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. It turns out that it blender does not deal with .dds files well, so the solution was to change the output file type to .png in Legion